Problema de CustomTkinter a la hora de cargar graficamente los widgets
les comento estoy haciendo un sistema que simula una agenda, es como una matriz, las filas son los horarios y estas, son todos botones cargados con el empaquetado grid. esta hecho con Custom tkinter. El problema es que cuando muevo a traves del scrollframe es que se bugea la carga grafica y se ve como se arrastran los objetos. Entiendo que debe ser que al ser muchos widgets demanda mucho al recrear los mismos. Estuve buscando soluciones con chat gpt de como optimizarlo pero no ayuda. Algun genio podria ayudarme porfavor? sevilla vos que sos un capo o cualquiera le agredeceria mucho

aca esta el codigo de como se crea la agenda
PD: EL GIF SE VE MEDIO LAG, pero el scrollbar va fluido
def agenda_maker(self, button_cords):
    self.get_controllers()
    self.personas = self.employedcontroller.employed_list_maker()
    self.horas = self.configurecontroller.get_hs_list()
    # Configurar la columna de horarios para tener un ancho fijo
    self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize = self.anchofilashs)
    

    # Ajustar el peso de las columnas de acuerdo al número de personas
    num_columns = len(self.personas)
    for col in range(1, num_columns + 1):
        self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(col, weight=1)

    # Colocar los encabezados de las horas en la primera columna
    for i, hora in enumerate(self.horas):
        btnhs = ctk.CTkButton(self.frame, text=self.horas[i], height=self.altofilas,
                              width=self.anchofilashs, fg_color=COLOR_CUERPO_PRINCIPAL, text_color="black",
                              border_width=1, border_color=COLOR_BORDES_AGENDA, corner_radius=0, hover=False)
        btnhs.grid(row=i + 1, column=0, padx=0, pady=0, sticky="ew")

    # Colocar los encabezados de los nombres en la primera fila
    for i, persona in enumerate(self.personas):
        btnhs = ctk.CTkButton(self.frame, text=persona, height=self.altofilas,
                              fg_color=COLOR_CUERPO_PRINCIPAL, text_color="black",
                              border_width=1, border_color=COLOR_BORDES_AGENDA, corner_radius=0, hover=False)
        btnhs.grid(row=0, column=i + 1, padx=0, pady=0, sticky="ew")

    for i, persona in enumerate(self.personas):
        for j, hora in enumerate(self.horas):
            btn = ctk.CTkButton(self.frame, text="", height=self.altofilas,
                                fg_color=COLOR_CUERPO_PRINCIPAL, hover_color="gray", corner_radius=0, 
                                border_width=0.5, border_color=COLOR_BORDES_AGENDA)
            btn.grid(row=j + 1, column=i + 1, padx=0, pady=0, sticky="ew")
            btn.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, p=persona, h=hora: button_cords(event,btn))
    

